# Conflict in git pull request

Tags: git

I have dev branch and I want to merge into main branch. but I am getting conflict.

which method is better to handle the conflict

Method 1: check out the dev branch and pull FROM main branch and the commit and push.
Method 2: Check out the dev branch and merge the main branch to it and then commit and push.

What is the difference between them ?

Comment: @eftshift0 yes I know, you have to do it, but couldn't find the differences between the two methods.

Comment: Oh, disregard my comment. Let me delete it.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same in most cases. The possible differences:

1. Some config variables are set, like `pull.rebase`, `pull.ff`. They affect the behavior of `git pull`. Without these variables, `git pull origin main` is roughly `git fetch origin main && git merge origin/main`. With `pull.rebase=true`, `git pull origin main` is approximately `git fetch origin main && git rebase origin/main`. They lead to different log graphs.
2. The head of `main` could be different. `git pull` always fetches the latest head of `main` from the remote repository while `git merge main` uses the local main. The local main could be the same with, behind, ahead of, or diverged from the remote main.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 is wrong, Method 2 is correct.

Method 1 doesn't make any sense. You usually push and pull to a branch with the same name. There should be a 1:1 correspondance between any branches you have on your local repo and with any remotes you have defined for that repo. Otherwise it becomes impossible to keep track of what code is where.

There are actually two ways of doing this, one of which is the preferred way and is supported by things like Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, the other is not.

## Preferred Way:

As you have described:

- check out the branch (dev) containing new work to be merged into the master branch
- either rebase it on top of master, or merge master into it
- resolve any conflicts
- then setup a pull request to merge dev into master, or just do the merge of dev into master manually (depending whether you are using a GUI like Gitlab etc or using a CLI)

Whether you choose the rebase method or merge method depends usually on what is most practical. A rebase makes a lot of sense when you have a series of commits on branch where everything is broadly independent of anything which has gone into master recently. A merge makes more sense if you have a sequence of commits which is coupled to the changes made on master recently.

As a rule of thumb, merging is *usually* less work than a rebase.

## Alternative Way:

This way might not be supported if you are working with a GUI which enforces a particular workflow. (Like Github etc) OR if you have rules defined to prevent comitting directly to master.

- checkout master
- merge in dev
- resolve conflicts and add a conflict resolving commit
- already on master branch, so done

It's the same as above, but symmetrically reversed. Obviously doesn't work in all situations, for reasons described above.

Comment: Method 1 is mentioned by bitbucket, to solve the conflict. (on the pull request ). I agree with you that the pull has different job, but this was mentioned by bitbucket.

Comment: @user3586286 can you post a link to the page here? It seems a bit odd - but then again with Git there are a lot of ways it can be used and various people have different opinions on how it should be used. It's likely whoever wrote the page wrote it thinking "well this works" and didn't think any more in depth about it.

Comment: Bitbucket note:


Step 1: Checkout the source branch and merge in the changes from the target branch. Resolve conflicts.

git checkout dev
git pull origin main

Step 2: After the merge conflicts are resolved, stage the changes accordingly, commit the changes and push.

git commit
git push origin HEAD
Step 3: Merge the updated pull request.